# append row to a specific column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```js
function dailyprofit() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Matt");
   var profit = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('O2').getValue();
   sheet.appendRow([,,,profit ]);
}
```

Hello, i'm attempting to use appendrow to put my variable into the last blank cell of row D, however appendRow does the entre row rather than just column D.
i would like the "profit" to be appended to row 362 rather than row 363 -> [see example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33umz.png)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sample code to get the last row of Column D:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Matt");
  var profit = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('O2').getValue();
  var colValues = sheet.getRange("D1:D").getValues();
  var count = colValues.filter(String).length
  sheet.getRange(count+1,4).setValue(profit);
```

### What it does?

1. Get all the column D values using `sheet.getRange("D1:D").getValues()`
2. Filter the array with string values and get its length/count. Empty cells will not be counted.
3. Increment the column D count by 1 and use [Sheet.getRange(row,column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) to get the cell below the non-empty cell in Column D. Use [Range.setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) to set the cell value.

### Sample Output:

[image]

---

### NOTE:

This will only work assuming you don't have an empty row in Column D.

If you have empty rows in your Column D, you might need to add few more offsets when incrementing the count.

**Example:**

[image]

- I have 2 empty header rows (rows 1 and 2). Therefore, the offset of row count should be +3.

**Sample Code:**

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Matt");
  var profit = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('O2').getValue();
  var colValues = sheet.getRange("D1:D").getValues();
  var count = colValues.filter(String).length
  sheet.getRange(count+3,4).setValue(profit);
```

Comment: this worked perfectly thanks for the help and the great explanation :)